# How to create a slideout menu like Facebook?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, ios8

I want to create a slideout menu like Facebook, when you click on right barbutton item it will show slideout view.

Same as I want to make slide view controller. My problem is every slideout example has set rootview controller in app delegate.

But my requirement is I want to ask the user first login, if the login success then want to navigate user to slideview controller.

How can I do that?

Comment: Try swrevealviewcontroller.. dont use appdelegate to set rootviewcontroller. make swrevealviewcontroller as your initial screen in storyboard then set your loginviewcontroller as its frontview by setting sw_front segue from swrcontroller to loginview controller

Comment: I have same requirement as yours . i have to show slideout menu from my third screen i done it perfectly the way mentioned above

Comment: Sorry i am unable to do that swrcontroller.. If you have any demo project can u send me pleas ..

Comment: sorry i have no demo project .. i done it in my realtime project

Comment: send me a demo setup project asas your requirement. to me. i will integrate swrevealviewcontroller .

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/download/1108364335859103/SlideMenu.zip

Comment: Before you go about doing that, have a look at this: http://blog.manbolo.com/2014/06/30/apple-on-hamburger-menus Hamburger/Slideout/Drawer menus are *really* discouraged by Apple